# How to access Laravel validation translations

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-validation

As we know, to use validators and translate messages we need to use `field.validatorname` with translated text.

So now I have `entry.php` file with my translation:

```
return [
    'validation'        => [
        'title.max'  => 'some text',
    ]
];
```

validator will use this text without a problem. The question is - how to access this text using `trans` / `Lang::get()` ?

For example using `trans('entry.validation.title.max')` won't work. I tried using `[]` for example `trans('entry.validation[title.max]')` but it also doesn't work.

The only way it works is using array dereference syntax:

```
trans('entry.validation')['title.max']
```

Is there any other way?

Comment: Laravel uses dot notation for arrays pretty much everywhere, so `title.max` is searching for `[title][max]` and you can't change it just like that. So either change your naming and conform to the framework way of handling it, eg. `title_max` or `'title' => [ 'max' => 'some text' ]` or do it your way down the line.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk But looking at http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#custom-error-messages if you want to have custom messages in array, you need to use `title.max` and not `title =>  ['max' => 'custom message']` if you don't want to put everything in one validation file or maybe. I pass to validator for example `trans('entry.validation')` where I store my translations. Or maybe I miss something here?

Comment: Well, you got it wrong. Check the very last example in linked paragraph of the docs. There you will find the way it works for **external files**, while the way you talk about works for inline providing messages.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk Hmm, but as I understand you can put here custom only in one file - validation.php and you don't pass it to your validators. Let's assume you have name field in many models. Translation for the world name may be different depending which model you validate. For Polish it could be for example nazwa or imię and if I use this method I think I won't be able use different translation if I don't change the field name in table in database  (form-model binding)